# Best way to deal with Encrypted USB user authentication

Tags: usb-drive

So I'm working with a client who wants the absolute highest level of security for his project.

I pitched him the idea of hardware user authentication with one of those encrypted USB drives with the keypads on them. The system is completely isolated from any network, as well as all physical access is biometrically secured.

I was thinking of using pamusb in conjunction with something like [this USB drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0711KDGML) from Amazon.

The only question I had was "Is the USB going to unlock the user without putting in the password?"

I'm not exactly sure how pamusb works, but if all it does is check UUID of the drive, then it might not work the way I might want. If anybody has experience with pamusb or encrypted flash drives, thanks!

Comment: Why are you preferring using encrypted USB drives over smart cards or devices that act similarly?

Comment: Because enterprise hardware is getting in the way of the budget, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Would U2F + local password be an acceptable way of authenticating?

Comment: I'm sure there are many ways of being secure, I would just like to know how my system would work.

Comment: How much of the USB is accessible before the PIN is entered?

Comment: It's on the person, and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78401/discussion-between-jrtapsell-and-m-loewenthal).

Comment: Can you check if you are able to join the chat?